# Collecting objects faster than std::vector

Tags: c++

I have a function that stores a lot of small objects (~16 bytes) in a vector, but it doesn't know in advance how many objects will be stored (imagine a recursive descent parser storing tokens for example).

```
std::vector<SmallObject> getObjects();
```

This is quite slow because of all the reallocation and copying (and apparently C++ even has to invoke the copy constructors [if you don't use an optimised version](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md) (see "Object Relocation").

There must be a better way to do things like this where all I am doing to construct the vector is appending things. For example I could have a singly linked list of blocks that are filled, and convert everything to a single vector at the end, so everything only has to be copied once.

Is there anything in Boost or the standard C++ library that would help with this? Or any particularly clever algorithms?

Edit: To be more concrete:

```
struct SmallObject {
    unsigned id;
    boost::icl::discrete_interval<unsigned> ival;
};
```

Comment: First off, is `SmallObject` `nothrow` move constructable?

Comment: I'd be surprised if `getObjects` doesn't use RVO/NRVO since it returns the vector by value, depending on how that vector is constructed internally

Comment: `std::deque` might be an alternative...

Comment: Is there any way you can estimate an upper bound on the number of objects you will want to store? For example, if you're reading these things from a file, it is at most the file size divided by 16, or the number of lines times two? In that case, you could already `reserve` that much capacity, which will allocate too much memory but prevent moves. Even if the upper bound is a bit too low, that's OK - at least it prevents all the small increases (2 -> 4 -> 10 -> 16) at the start of the loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't think so. See edit.

Comment: @CoryKramer: I don't see how that is relevant. It isn't the returning that is the issue (and actually in my real code it is passed by reference - forgot about that).

Comment: @CompuChip: Yes! Good idea! Unfortunately it is quite a high upper bound but I will try that.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Nice one, I'll try that.

Comment: You could reserve a number of slots in the vector.  Try using an average of your quantities.

Answer (score 0):

The question which container is most efficient is always best answered by "it depends" and "measure it!".

Without any more information about your specific situation, there are two 'obvious' possibilities:

### Use a linked list

The STL has two linked lists by default: a singly linked list `std::forward_list` and a doubly linked list `std::deque`. Moreover there is `std::list` which is usually the doubly-linked variant. Some quotes from the documentation:

> [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) [...] is implemented as a singly-linked list and essentially does not have any overhead compared to its implementation in C. Compared to std::list this container provides more space efficient storage when bidirectional iteration is not needed.
>
> [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) [...] is usually implemented as a doubly-linked list. Compared to std::forward_list this container provides bidirectional iteration capability while being less space efficient.
>
> [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (double-ended queue) [..] insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates pointers or references to the rest of the elements.
>
> As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays

## Reserve space in a vector

If there is any way you can estimate an upper bound on the number of objects you will want to store, you can use that to `reserve` some space in advance.

For example, if you're reading these objects from a file, the number of objects may be at most the file size divided by 16, or the number of lines times two, or some other quick and easy calculation that you can do before constructing these objects.

In that case, if you `reserve` the capacity, you will allocate too much memory but prevent moves. Even if the upper bound is a bit too low, that's OK: you may still need to double the capacity once or twice but at least you prevent all the small increases (2 -> 4 -> 10 -> 16) at the start of the loop.

Comment: STL *has* two linked lists, of which the second, however, is `std::list`; `std::deque` is *not* a linked list (see your own citation...).

Comment: I wouldn't call a `std::deque` a doubly linked list.  It is a hybrid of a list and an array where each node is some fixed size array.  Gives you the best of both worlds with the trade off that the objects are not contiguous

Comment: Actually there is nowhere written that internally a list of arrays must be used at all. If the iterators are implemented such that they do not invalidate, a `std::vector` of arrays is just as valid... Admitted, though, my own ideas for implementation go into the hybrid approach, too...

Comment: `std::forward_list` and `std::list` are almost certainly *terrible* choices since they'll need one allocation for each object and I have a lot of small objects. They're almost never the right choice anyway. `std::deque` looks much more reasonable since apparently most implementation allocate in blocks.